# Возможно ли локально (не на сервере) прочитать file.txt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Используя jQuery, возможно ли из file.txt прочитать и вывести в тег параграфа не на сервере ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример использования File API:

```js
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  if (!file) return;
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('filecontent').innerText = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"></input>
<p id="filecontent"></p>
```

Comment: а просто без input вывести нельзя ?

Comment: Без `input` браузер не имеет доступа к файлам. Иначе бы любой сайт мог прочитать любые ваши файлы

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Нельзя. В целях безопасности, FileReader может читать только те файлы, которые явно выбрал пользователь.

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).  Но только в том случае когда пользователь сам выбрал данный файл с компьютера с помощью input:file.

1. Проверить что FileAPI поддерживается браузером
2. Получить объект файла File из input:file.
3. Прочитать файл с помощью FileReader в строку
4. Эту строку добавить как текст в параграф.

Вот [неплохая статья](https://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) на эту тему

Comment: файл ридер не работает локально , я читал эту статью уже

Comment: Тогда никак. Иначе можно было бы незаметно для пользователя просматривать его файлы

Comment: @МаксимЛенский почему не работает? Работает, см. пример в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "file.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        $("p.text").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: перечитайте вопрос ... на ajax это и первоклашки могут ...

Comment: написано же ... не на  сервере, минусовал не я